# マクロでヘッダーを割り振る方法（複数行）

Tags: emeditor

a■ああ■いい……
b■うう■ええ……
c■おお■かか……

というデータをマクロで

a
aああ
aいい……
b
bうう
bええ……
c
cおお
cかか……

に変換したいのですが、区切りの「■」の数は不定で、「a」や「ああ」などの長さも不定です。
ご教示、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re1 = editor.regex;
re1.Engine = eeExFindRegexOnigmo;
re1.Pattern = "^(.*?)(■.*)$";
for( var yLine = document.GetLines(); yLine > 0; yLine-- ){
    line = document.GetLine( yLine , eeGetLineWithNewLines );
    m = re1.Find( line );
    if( ! m ) continue;

    tag = m.Item(1).Value;
    str = m.Item(2).Value;
    re2 = editor.regex;
    re2.Engine = eeExFindRegexOnigmo;
    re2.Pattern = "■+([~■]*)";
    re2.Global = true;
    str = re2.Replace( str, "\n" + tag + "\\1" );
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, yLine );
    document.selection.SelectLine();
    document.selection.Text = tag + str + "\n";
}
```

Comment: うまく行きました。たいへん助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

split() を使えばもっとシンプルでした

```
for( var yLine = document.GetLines(); yLine > 0; yLine-- ){
    var para = document.GetLine( yLine ).split( /■+/ )
    if( para.length <= 1 )  continue;

    var tag = para[0];
    var str = tag + "\n";
    for( var i = 1; i < para.length; i++ ){
        str += tag + para[i] + "\n";
    }

    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, yLine );
    document.selection.SelectLine();
    document.selection.Text = str;
}
```